# XPATH how to get the attr by selecting the class

Tags: web-scraping, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

I want to get the value of the attibute of an image like 'src'. also the image have a classname, i select the image using the class name, but how can i get the attribute?

```
<img src="http://somelink.jpg" class="img-fluid">
```

here's how i use the xpath selector to select an image using the classname

```
//img[@class="img-fluid"]
```

how can i get the value of an attr of an image "src"?
so i'll have the link "http://somelink.jpg"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below xpath to get the `src` value.

```
//img[@class="img-fluid"]/@src
```

For example, you can get `src` attribute of all *avatar images* in this page using the below xpath.

```
//*[contains(@class, "user-gravatar")]//img/@src
```

You may also take a look at this xpath [cheatsheet](https://gist.github.com/LeCoupa/8c305ec8c713aad07b14).